# how to get start date of latest dept in which working

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the record of emp current working dept with start date

Data, in below data Grp column is I've derived to get the 3rd last record, which is the correct result.

```
loginName   emp_name    dept_id     dept_name                   startDate   endDate     Grp
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        18-09-17    19-09-17    1
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        19-09-17    28-09-17    1
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        28-09-17    09-11-17    1
KK          KKLeo       5647        POLO Business               09-11-17    15-03-19    2
KK          KKLeo       5647        POLO Business               15-03-19    16-04-19    2
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   16-04-19    03-05-19    3
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   03-05-19    11-10-19    3
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   11-10-19    22-07-20    3
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   22-07-20    26-08-20    3
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        26-08-20    17-02-21    4
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        17-02-21    19-02-21    4
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        19-02-21    null        4
```

query tried so far

```
select login_name,
       emp_name,
       dept_id,
       dept_name,
       startDate,
       endDate, 
       sum (counter) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_name order by startDate) grp
                            from (
                                    select login_name,
                                           emp_name,
                                           dept_id,
                                           dept_name,
                                           startDate,
                                           endDate,
                                           CASE WHEN DEPT_NAME = LAG(DEPT_NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY login_name, emp_name, dept_id ORDER BY startDate)
                                                THEN 0
                                                ELSE 1
                                           END counter
                                    FROM empdepthist 
                               )
```

Am not able to think ahead, that how can I use `Grp` now to get 3rd last record as a output. Data is having only one `emp` details but it could be many.

expected output

```
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        26-08-20    17-02-21
```

Update

```
oginName   emp_name    dept_id     dept_name                   startDate   endDate     PartitionByEMpName   GroupInPartiton    
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        18-09-17    19-09-17    1                   a
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        19-09-17    28-09-17    1                   a
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        28-09-17    09-11-17    1                   a
KK          KKLeo       5647        POLO Business               09-11-17    15-03-19    1                   b
KK          KKLeo       5647        POLO Business               15-03-19    16-04-19    1                   b
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   16-04-19    03-05-19    1                   c
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   03-05-19    11-10-19    1                   c
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   11-10-19    22-07-20    1                   c
KK          KKLeo       5649        POLO Buss-Fixed Sales Mkt   22-07-20    26-08-20    1                   c   
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        26-08-20    17-02-21    1                   d   
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        17-02-21    19-02-21    1                   d
KK          KKLeo       5652        POLO Business – Tech        19-02-21    null        1                   d
```

Is it correct to visualize in this way ? `PartitionByEMpName` coulmn value is derived from Partition by `loginName` and `GroupInPartiton` is derived from `DEFINE same_dept AS FIRST(dept_id) = dept_id` and once its in this format, then Pattern and measures will work on this data.  Is correct ?

Comment: `row_number` the output as needed and take the rows with nmbr = 3. My guess is `row_number() over(partition by emp_name order by    Grp DESC,  startDate DESC)`

Comment: @Serg, but nmbr =3 wont be always the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   empdepthist
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY loginname
  ORDER BY startdate
  MEASURES
    FIRST(emp_name) AS emp_name,
    FIRST(dept_id) AS dept_id,
    FIRST(dept_name) AS dept_name,
    FIRST(startDate) AS startdate,
    FIRST(endDate) AS enddate
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN (same_dept+ $)
  DEFINE same_dept AS FIRST(dept_id) = dept_id
)
```

It works by:

1. `PARTITION` the rows `BY loginname`.
2. Within each partition, `ORDER` the rows `BY startdate`.
3. `DEFINE` the `same_dept` pattern as sequential rows (within the partition in the given order) where the `FIRST(dept_id)` in the match equals the `dept_id` of each other row in the match.
4. The `PATTERN` to be matched is at the end of the ordering (`$`) which matches the pattern defined as one-or-more rows (`+`) matching the `same_dept` pattern.
5. When you have matched the pattern, return only `ONE ROW PER MATCH`.
6. That row will contain the columns in the `PARTITION BY` clause and the values defined in the `MEASURES` clause which, in this case, is the value from the `FIRST` row of the match.

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | LOGINNAME | EMP_NAME | DEPT_ID | DEPT_NAME | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | KK | KKLeo | 5652 | POLO Business – Tech | 26-08-20 | 17-02-21 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6fcde52c7e2ad7646cc90933e20cdbc7)*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237279/discussion-between-freshtransistor-and-mt0).

Comment: sorry..yes its only one partition having 12 records. <<DEFINE same_dept AS FIRST(dept_id) = dept_id>> Is this capturing all dept_ids when it gets changed in sequential order of 12 records ? And once all are captured, then from out that records its pulling the last record...correct sir ?

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6). The `DEFINE` clause defines which group (within a partition) the row belongs to. In this case, all rows in the group have the same `DEPT_ID`.

Comment: can you please check the update part in question ? trying to visualize data on how query is working on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using window functions.  One method is simply to enumerate the rows (in reverse), once by employee and one by department.  These are the same for the last rows:

```
select loginname, emp_name, dept_id, min(startdate), max(startdate), 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_name order by startdate desc) as seqnum_e,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_name , dept_id order by startdate desc) as seqnum_ed
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_e = seqnum_ed
group by loginname, emp_name, dept_id, dept_name;
```

If your table is at all large, you can compare the performance of this approach to the `match recognize` approach.

Comment: cool perspective